# Scrolling in Appium

Tags: appium

I am automating a Tablet application using Appium + Java.
In a screen, I have 100+ fields (Textbox + Dropdown) to automate which has scroll view.

To automate those 100+ fields, I have listed down all the IDs(of those textbox and dropdown in that screen) along with the test Cases and Test Data in separate Excel sheets.
My code runs in a loop, picks Test Case, its Data and relevant ID and executes.
So, my code looks like:

```
    loop : for(int j = 1; j <= fieldCount; j++)
    {
        objElementRepositoryLibrary.setElementRepositoryDataLibrary(j);

        switch(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementType()) {

        case "AutoPopulated":
            System.out.println(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue() + " is Autopopulated");
            break;

        case "Dropdown": 
            ElementOperation.checkElementState(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());

            if(ElementOperation.ElementAcceess.equals(false))
                System.out.println(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue() + " is disabled");
            else
                objElementOperation.dropdownSelectListner(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue(), field[0][j-1]);
            break;

        case "Button":
            ElementOperation.checkElementState(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());

            if(ElementOperation.ElementAcceess.equals(false)) {
                System.out.println(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue() + " is disabled");
                break loop;
            }
            else if(field[0][j-1].equals(""))
                System.out.println("Checking for Null value");
            else if(field[0][j-1].equals("Yes") && ElementRepositoryLibrary.getFieldName().equals("QR Scanner"))
                objElementOperation.buttonClickListner(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());
            else if(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getFieldName().contains("Capture Document"))
                objElementOperation.captureDocument(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());
                break;

        default :
            objElementOperation.textboxSetListner(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementType(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), 
                    ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue(), field[0][j-1]);
            break;
        }   
    }
```

ISSUE: After filling few(say 7) fields, it is giving me `NoSuchElementException` because I have to scroll in the screen to move to the next fields(It goes like: screen contains 7 fields & you have to scroll to view the fields below and **automator** will nor recognize the `element` until it is viewed in the screen).

What I had tried is, I did `catch` for `NoSuchElementException` and performed Scroll operation. But it is not the proper way to do because if the element which has been searched is not present in actual, then also it will catch `NoSuchElementException` and perform scroll operation.

Suggest some good way to eliminate this issue. Let me know if any detail needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the answer to my question:
Before starting `switch` case, I performed one check:

```
ElementOperation.checkElementAvailable(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());
        if(ElementOperation.ElementAvailablity == true) {
            switch(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementType()) {
}
```

where `checkElementAvailable` is:

```
public static boolean checkElementAvailable(AndroidDriver<?> eleOpDriver, String locator, String elementValue) throws Exception {
    try {
        ElementAvailablity = findElement(eleOpDriver, locator, elementValue).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Element Availablity for " + elementValue + " is " + ElementAvailablity);
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("General exception for " + elementValue);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
return ElementAvailablity;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will work but in case if element is not displayed which you specified tin `try` block will keep on pooling the element till `implicit wait`. So before scrolling you wait time will be large. In my answer, if element is not available the final `List` will have `null` value, check the size and perform scroll. Correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll till the element having text. Try below code.

```
driver.scrollTo("Your partial text");
```

Approach 2:

```
isFoundElement = driver.findElements(myElement).size() > 0;
while (!isFoundElement) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: First of all, `scrollTo` method has been depricated (Correct me if I am wrong), so I have created swipe operation which works fine.
But the issue is, where should I put that method.

Comment: Yes `scrollTo` method is depricated, you can try using element `isDisplayed()` method in condition loop instead of try catch?

Comment: added 2nd approach. This will not wait for implicit wait timeout and execution will be fast. Hope this help.

Comment: the way which you had given will work but in the circumstances that `myElement` should be know before execution.

As you can see my code has loop, so I will not be certain that when and which element I should call for `isFoundElement`